# Can RegexParser support patterns with (white)spaces in them?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

We want to create regex patterns with whitespace.  However that seems to conflict with the token parsing done by the RegexParser: the pieces of the input character stream are broken into separate tokens before the individual Rules (/Parsers) ever see the inputs. Therefore the Rules will never be able to match their intended inputs.

Is there any workaround or suggested approach for this?

Comment: Please add examples of input strings, your attempted regex(es), the unwanted outcome and the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The RegexParser skips whitespace by default:

> The parsing methods call the method skipWhitespace (defaults to true) and, if true, skip any whitespace before each parser is called.

[RegexParser Doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.2/scala-parser-combinators/#scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers)

Overriding `skipWhitespace()` should fix your issue.